# how can I load json multilevel in siddhi?

Tags: siddhi

I am trying to load a JSON with multilevel values. For example:

```
{
    "id": "parkingcity-02",
    "type": "parking",
    "parkingMax": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": "100",
        "metadata": {}
     },
     "descripcion": {
         "type": "Text",
         "value": "Parking number 2",
         "metadata": {}
     },
     "freeParking": {
          "type": "Number",
          "value": "80",
          "metadata": {}
     }

}
```

I want to get the value field to parkingMax and freeParking.

Finally, the values will be subtracted and printed.

Thank you very much.

Best regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those values with a custom mapping.

```
@source(type=<type>, receiver.url=<your_url>, @map(type = 'json', 
     @attributes(parkingMax = '$.parkingMax.value', freeParking = '$.freeParking.value')))
define stream InputStream (parkingMax long, freeParking long);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the siddhi-execution-json extension[1] and achieve your requirement. Please find the below sample siddhi codes extract the above-mentioned field.

```
define stream InputStream(json string);
from IpStream
select json:getString(json,"$.parkingMax") as parkingMax, json:getString(json,"$.freeParking") as freeParking
insert into OutputStream;
```

Please node that you need to provide the above-mentioned JSON to the input stream

[1] - https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-json/api/latest/

Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Your code work, but in my case is better the other solution.